# Using $limit and $offset to get more than 1,000 rows on a SODA API

Tags: python, json, socrata, soda

I am pulling data with a SODA API using the following code in Python

```
response = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json')
```

The dataset contains 434,865 rows but when I use the API, it only returns the first 1,000 rows. I saw on another question that `$limit` can be used to get the first 50,000 rows but how would I combine this with `$offset` to get all 434,865 rows?

** I figured out how to use `$offset` and now have the resulting code, is there any way to condense this?

```
response1 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000')
response2 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=50001')
response3 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=100002')
response4 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=150003')
response5 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=200004')
response6 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=250005')
response7 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=300006')
response8 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=350007')
response9 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=400008')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referred to as `paging`, and you can find documentation for example here: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html

In there, it is also specified that there are two versions of API:

- v2.0, where `$limit` can be max 50,000
- v2.1, where `$limit` is unlimited

The endpoint you are using seems to be support v2.1, at least based on this https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/healthdata.gov/uqq2-txqb so you should be able to use a large value for `$limit` and retrieve the entire set at once.

Going the paging route, the `$offset` value is `0-based`, hence your queries should be properly rewritten as:

```
response1 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000')
response2 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2xqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=50000')
response3 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2xqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=100000')
response4 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2xqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=150000')
```

Note the alignment on multiples of `$limit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
response1 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000')
response2 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=50001')
response3 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=100002')
response4 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=150003')
response5 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=200004')
response6 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=250005')
response7 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=300006')
response8 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=350007')
response9 = requests.get('https://healthdata.gov/resource/uqq2-txqb.json?$limit=50000&$offset=400008')
```

Comment: The offset is incorrect and records are being dropped with these values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialize variables for pagination

limit = 50000
offset = 0
data = []

while True:

    # Set query parameters
    params = {
        '$limit': limit,
        '$offset': offset
    }

    # Make a GET request to the API endpoint with the query parameters
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```